# Правильно ли так экономить оперативную память?

Tags: php, fopen

**Дано:**
Текстовый файл, скажем, с 1 000 000 строк (+-12 мб). Нужно прочитать этот файл построчно и обработать каждую строку.
За один запуск скрипта файл может быть прочитан до 100 раз.
Одновременно к файлу могут обращаться до 100 параллельных процессов, только на чтение, записи нет.

Работает это все в фоне, скорость не сильно важна.

**Вариант 1:**

```
$fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/memory_test.txt', 'rb');

if(is_resource($fp)){
    for($i = 1; $i <=100; $i++){
        while (!feof($fp)){
            $line = trim(fgets($fp, 512));
            //do something
        }
        rewind($fp);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

**Результат 1:**

Done time: **11.448186159134**
Memory peak usage: **421.52 kb**

**Вариант 2:**

```
$fp = fopen(__DIR__.'/memory_test.txt', 'rb');
$lines = [];
if(is_resource($fp)) {
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $lines[] = trim(fgets($fp, 512));
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

for($i = 1; $i <=100; $i++){
    foreach($lines as $line){
        //do something
    }
}
```

**Результат 2:**

Done time: **0.78291392326355**
Memory peak usage: **54 mb**

Первый вариант заметно проигрывает в скорости, но выигрывает в использовании памяти, что с учетом того, что скрипт выполняется до 20 минут, время не критичное.

Второй вариант расходует заметно больше памяти, что, с учетом 100 параллельных процессов на таск, - весьма ощутимо, но как я подозреваю, меньше нагружает процессор.

Какой вариант предпочтительнее, что бы не уложить сервер на лопатки? Что можете предложить вы?

Спасибо.

Comment: Зависит от вашего сервера и ваших потребностей, универсального ответа не будет

Comment: Смысл вопроса непонятен. Если на сервере есть лишние 6 гигов памяти, надо использовать второй вариант. Если нет - то первый. Это очень простая арифметика.

Comment: почему в качестве хранилища данных выбран файл? Можно ведь наверное то же самое закэшировать в памяти один раз redis/memcached и т.п. и исключить обращение к дисковой системе?  Все ли строки файла вы обрабатываете на повторных проходах по нему, может можно оставить в памяти только часть, и не читать его повторно целиком? Или может можно разбить файл на несколько непересекающихся частей* Что там вообще за данные в этой файле, мб это решается простой сменой хранения  на СУБД, а то поди ищите в нем что-то, а потом зависимые строки еще раз ищите. Мб решается простым sql-запросом, а не вот этим вот

Comment: @teran Скрипт получает данные по сети и сравнивает их, в т.ч. со строкаи из файла. Сколько нужно строк заранее неизвестно, может быть 1, а может быть и все.

Comment: @teran Если даже взять условный memcached, для использования данных их все равно нужно взять из кеша и загрузить в память в каждом процессе, а банальный unset не освобождает выделенную под переменную память (т.е. даже если снести переменную после перебора, php не освободит память сразу, а может и не освободит вообще до завершения). И теперь имеем еще и инстанс memcached, который тоже занимает память...

Comment: относительное кэширования - основной посыл был в том что вы не насилуете файловую систему

Answer (score 0):

Загружать дисковую подсистему 100 кратным повторением чтения файла - это не лучший вариант, так как это бутылочное горлышко в системе. Поэтому предпочтительным будет второй вариант. 54 МБ по нынешним временам не так уж и много, а если всё-таки нужно экономить память, то тут можно придумать кой-какую оптимизацию.

Текстовый файл содержит много избыточной информации (10х), поэтому она может быть предварительно обработана, а потом размещена в памяти для последующего использования, что не только сэкономит память, но и улучшит производительность.

Comment: Дисковая подсистема тоже использует кеширование. Если читать с диска много раз подряд один и тот же файл, который не изменяется при этом, то скорее всего второе и все последующие чтения будут идти из кэша, если его будет хватать на размер этого файла. Причём, этот кэш будет точно использоваться в отличие от самостоятельных попыток сделать кэш в приложении, которые должны учитывать многопоточность и прочее. Так что ещё неизвестно, какой вариант на самом деле будет эффективнее. (Минус не мой, если что.)

Comment: @CrazyElf Я исхожу из того, что это не единственное приложение на сервере. Что будет кешировать дисковая подсистема - одному богу известно. Она точно не знает, что нужно кешировать именно эти данные, и её кешем никак нельзя управлять. Всё равно она является узким местом.

Comment: Если с диска много чего ещё читают одновременно, то да, кэш может и не сохранить в себе этот файл. Но вероятность, что файл, к которому в данный момент много и часто обращаются, будет в кэше, всё-таки довольно большой.

Comment: Диск активно используется, остановились на втором варианте. перейдем к первому, если памяти начнет не хватать. Благодарю, за ответ и комментарии по существу.

Comment: Ну, хотя бы upvote в качестве благодарности. Но рад, что помог, в любом случае. И советую обратить внимание на второй абзац прежде, чем переходить к первому варианту, если вдруг прижмёт.